# Update YouTube Playlist status, Title and Description using YouTube API v3

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to update the `status(public, private, unlisted)` of playlist using YouTube API v3 in java.

```
YouTube.Playlists.Update playlistUpdateCommand =  youTube.playlists().update(arg0, arg1);
```

`arg0` is a string
`arg1` is a playlist

what should be the argument `arg0` in update method. and how i can set the title, description and status of the playlist.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I could able to manage update the status of the playlist.

To update the status, title and description of a playlist first we need OAuth and you must be the owner of the playlist. Later we need to build the playlist by setting the status, title and description (which ever you desire to change).

Title and description are set through PlaylistSnippet and status is set by PlaylistStatus. Now set the these two to playlist as shown in below code

```
    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
            .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
            .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
            .build();
    credential.setRefreshToken(getAccessToken());


    youTube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
        .setApplicationName("API Project")
        .build();


    PlaylistSnippet playlistSnippet = new PlaylistSnippet();
        playlistSnippet.setTitle("My Title of the playlist  " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        playlistSnippet.setDescription("A private playlist created with the YouTube API v3");
        PlaylistStatus playlistStatus = new PlaylistStatus();
        playlistStatus.setPrivacyStatus("private"); //private, public, unlisted

    Playlist youTubePlaylist = new Playlist();
        youTubePlaylist.setSnippet(playlistSnippet); 
        youTubePlaylist.setStatus(playlistStatus);
        youTubePlaylist.setId("PLEv-m2yWNXmS-xOK5GCQ6i6KMFuQcjOlo");  //playlist id starts with PL

    // Now playlist is ready now create update command and execute it

    YouTube.Playlists.Update playlistUpdateCommand = youTube.playlists().update("snippet,status", youTubePlaylist);

    Playlist playlistUpdated = playlistUpdateCommand.execute();


    System.out.println("New Playlist name: " + playlistUpdated.getSnippet().getTitle());
        System.out.println(" - Privacy: " + playlistUpdated.getStatus().getPrivacyStatus());
        System.out.println(" - Description: " + playlistUpdated.getSnippet().getDescription());
```